# ¿Cómo puedo obtener todos los campos en php de un formulario te forma automática sin saber la cantidad de campos que haya ni sus name?

Tags: php

La idea es que tengo en un formulario se puedan añadir `inputs` de forma dinámica, por lo que una vez que el usuario realice un `submit`, saber de forma dinámica la cantidad de `inputs` que hay, como si recorriésemos los campos con un `foreach`.

¿ Hay alguna manera de hacerlo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al hacer el submit con método post automáticamente la variable $_POST es un arreglo que te almacena toda la información enviada del formulario, puede hacerle el foreach directamente:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    # code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar serializarlos. checa este link.

[jQuery serialize() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serialize.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes recorrer todos los valores enviados por `POST` con un bucle, ya que es un array, y contar el número de campos enviados, en el ejemplo se utiliza el bucle para el contador, también puedes consultar directamente el tamaño del `array $_POST`.

```
$n_campos = 0;

foreach ($_POST as $campo => $valor) {
  $n_campos++; // recoge el número de campos
  echo "el valor de ".$campo." es ".$valor;
}
echo "número de campos del formulario: ".$n_campos;
```

Answer (score 0):

yo uso el siguiente fragmento de codigo

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    ${$key} = trim(addslashes(strip_tags($value)));
}
```

esto me genera variables con de forma automatica que utilizan el mismo name como nombre de variables.

si quiero imprimirlas por pantalla:

llamo a esta funcion:

```
$this->PrintVar();
```

que ejecuta este código:

```
function PrintVar() {
        echo "Las variables que fueron enviadas vacias son rellenadas con '0' <br><br>";
        echo '<div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Tipo</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Valor</th>
                                <th>Sobre Escrita</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        ';
        $c = 0;
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            ${$key} = trim(addslashes(strip_tags($value)));
            if (empty(${$key}) || ${$key} == NULL || ${$key} === '' || ${$key} === ' ') {
                $value  = 0;
                ${$key} = trim(addslashes(strip_tags($value)));
                echo "<tr><td>" . gettype(${$key}) . "</td><td>" . print_r("$" . $key . "</td><td>|" . $value . "|</td><td>Sobre Escrita</td></tr>", TRUE);
            } else {
                echo "<tr><td>" . gettype(${$key}) . "</td><td>" . print_r("$" . $key . "</td><td>|" . $value . "|</td><td></td></tr>", TRUE);
            }
            $c++;
        }
        echo '</tbody></table></div>';
        echo 'total de variables Computadas: ' . $c . '<br>';
    }
```